# How function gets inside the table in Lua?

Tags: oop, class, lua

I am reading the [chapter 16.4 of Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.4.html) and I can't get one thing in the last example:

  `function newAccount (initialBalance)
      local self = {
        balance = initialBalance,
        LIM = 10000.00,
      }`

```
  local extra = function ()
    if self.balance > self.LIM then
      return self.balance*0.10
    else
      return 0
    end
  end

  local getBalance = function ()
    return self.balance + self.extra() -- this line is the problematic one
  end

  ...
```

HOW the "extra" function has become a "self.extra" one?! I don't see anything which makes it attached to the separate "self" table!

Comment: Don't take my word for it, but this seems to be an oversight from the documentation writers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been corrected in the second edition of the book to

```
local getBalance = function ()
  return self.balance + extra()
end
```